# How do you hook an editor for TFS 2010 WF BuildProcessTemplate arguments for built-in types that have a converter?

Tags: tfsbuild, workflow-foundation-4, uitypeeditor

I've followed the [Team Foundation Server 2010 book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470943327)'s custom editor for a `dictionary<string,string>` and can't get it to go. I have another custom [editor](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/17/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-6-Use-custom-type-for-an-argument.aspx) in the same assembly, and consumed by the same build template that works.

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067010/how-to-force-use-of-custom-uitypeeditor-for-system-types) hints at it being a `TypeConverter` issue, but I don't think any part of a custom build assembly is just run when it is loaded.

I'm getting the default generic Collection Editor instead of mine.

I have tried using code more like my credential `UITypeEditor` uses, and then tried typing exactly what's in the book for a `UITypeEditor`. The dialog itself should not matter unless it was throwing an exception, but I'd think that would popup somewhere visible rather than just loading the default editor.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because the IDE is not able to find your custom type. I hit the same issue last year - http://www.neovolve.com/post/2010/06/24/Full-support-for-custom-types-in-TFS-Build-2010-build-definition-editor.aspx. Try putting your custom assembly into the Visual Studio PrivateAssemblies directory and the recycle the IDE.

Comment: On my machine, or the build controller/agents? It finds one editor in the same assembly, but not the other?

Comment: On your local machine. This is because editing the build definition is only done there. The build server (controller/agent) doesn't care about the UI for the definition as it is already executing that definition as xml.

Comment: but why would this be it even when the other custom editor in the same assembly does load?

Comment: I have no idea. I have seen that other people have had inconsistent behaviour with customisations of the build definition dialog so nothing really surprises me at this point.

The only other thing that comes to mind is to look at assembly binding failures using the Fusion Log Viewer. Maybe that will another point of failure.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, i'm a big fan of your blog/code around this subject area. However the copy to private assemblies didn't work, even after restarting VS2010 ultimate, checking fusion log next.

Comment: Fusion Assembly Binding Log Viewer run locally turned up nothing helpful even when set to log all binds to disk.